# Type Error: contract.XXX is not a function

Tags: solidity, remix, ethers.js, polygon

I am working on a smart contract that allows you to create Crypto Estates so that other addresses can inherit your crypto assets upon death or lost keys.

I have the following smart contract function:

```
struct Estate_Struct {
    uint estate_id;
    address parent_address;
    address child_address;
    uint seconds_to_hold;
    uint wei_stored;
    uint date_estate_created;
    address nft_contract_address;
    uint nft_token_id;
    address erc_20_contract_address;
    uint erc_20_tokens_stored;
  }

  mapping(uint => Estate_Struct) estates;

  function make__regular_estate(uint _seconds_to_hold, address child_address) public payable {
    Estate_Struct memory new_estate;
    new_estate.wei_stored = msg.value;
    new_estate.estate_id = num_of_estates;
    new_estate.parent_address = msg.sender;
    new_estate.child_address = child_address;
    new_estate.seconds_to_hold = _seconds_to_hold;
    new_estate.date_estate_created = block.timestamp;
    num_of_estates += 1;
    emit print_estate_id(num_of_estates - 1);
  }
```

I have deployed it to Polygon [here](https://polygonscan.com/address/0xaffb57734a694b470b414a7bce1720ec9355d77f).

I am now trying to call it in a React app but it's giving me:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: contract.make_regular_estate is not a function

My React code is:

```
const CreateRegularEstate = async () => {
    console.log("Create Regular Estate called")
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    let contract = new ethers.Contract(contract_address, abi, signer);
    console.log(contract)
    let wei_to_hold = String(one_eth_in_wei * newEstate.amountToHold)
    let overrides = {value: wei_to_hold}
    let seconds_to_hold = newEstate.daysToHold
    contract.make_regular_estate(seconds_to_hold, newEstate.childAddress, overrides);
    setNewEstate({amountToHold: null, daysToHold: null, childAddress: null, parentAddress: '', tokenId: null, contractAddress: null })
  }
```

And also when I log the contract object I can see the function does exist on the contract even though the error message says it does not. Does anybody have any advice? I have triple checked the ABI which is correct and the contract address.

Comment: Doe the function in the contract has a double underscore `_` after make? solidity => `make__regular_estate`, javascript => `make_regular_estate`.